# Maximum length series of shifts in Google OR-tools employee scheduling

Tags: python, runtime, scheduling, or-tools

I'm developing a nurse scheduling program for one of the departments of the hospital I work with in Python. Various examples of such programs already exist and are shared online. One of these is the following: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py

So far I have managed to adapt the code in the link above to include various types of labour regulations as well as individual nurse preferences. However I keep struggling to implement the following rule:

- Employees cannot work more than 5 consecutive days.

The code natively supports bounds on the length of series of the same shift type (e.g. forbid n consecutive morning shifts or night shifts). However, there is no way to limit the length of series of back-to-back shifts if they are not of the same type (e.g. night/night/morning/night/morning).

I managed to implement this rule by adding the following piece of code:

```
    for e in range(num_employees):
            for d in range(num_days):                 
                   model.Add(work[e, 0, d] == 1).OnlyEnforceIf( (work[e, 1, d-5] or work[e, 2, d-5] or work[e, 3, d-5] or work[e, 4, d-5] )
                                                                and (work[e, 1, d-4] or work[e, 2, d-4] or work[e, 3, d-4] or work[e, 4, d-4] )
                                                                and (work[e, 1, d-3] or work[e, 2, d-3] or work[e, 3, d-3] or work[e, 4, d-3] )
                                                                and (work[e, 1, d-2] or work[e, 2, d-2] or work[e, 3, d-2] or work[e, 4, d-2] )
                                                                and (work[e, 1, d-1] or work[e, 2, d-1] or work[e, 3, d-1] or work[e, 4, d-1] ))
```

However, this implementation increases the run-time of the program drastically (from 30 seconds without the constraints, to about 15 minutes including it). Therefore I'm looking for a way to prohibit employees from being scheduled 5 or more consecutive days that doesn't increase run-time as much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adapt the code by limiting the length of off_shift.not() literals.

Comment: Hi Laurent, could you be a little more specific as to what you mean by off_shift literals? If I'm correct these have not been implemented. How do I do so?

Comment: In the above example, O is off, M is morning, A is afternoon, N is night. Thus non working is O. So for a given day `d` and employee `e`, ` work[e, 0, d]` is true if this employee is not working on that day. Thus `work[e, 0, d].not()` is true iif this employee is working. You can constraint the max length of these literals.

Answer (score 3):

***ANSWER***

I implemented the changes @LaurentPerron suggested below using the following lines of code:

```
max_seq_length = 5
for e in range(num_employees):
    works = [work[e, 0, d].Not() for d in range(num_days)]
    variables, coeffs = add_soft_sequence_constraint(
           model, works, 0, 0, 0, max_seq_length, max_seq_length, 0, 
           'shift_constraint(employee %i, shift %i)' % (e, 0))
    obj_bool_vars.extend(variables)
    obj_bool_coeffs.extend(coeffs)
```

Comment: Hey, can you tell us how the runtime behaved? Was it basically the same as before this constraint?

Comment: @CjojureMostly, when adding this constraint the runtime drastically increases. The way I set up the program it took about 5-10 as long for the computer to come up with a solution. Therefore I would advice to decrease runtime as much as possible before implementing it(I once had to wait over 24 hours for my schedule to be completed)

Answer (score 0):

couldn't we just add an AddBoolOr constraint on the consecutive off shifts instead of the 'add_soft_sequence_constraint' function and the .Not() literals? i.e., we enforce that there is no sequence of length hard_max that does not have an off-shift in it. sample code, modified from the example file:

```
max_seq_length = 5
for e in range(num_employees):
    works = [work[e, 0, d] for d in range(num_days)]
    for start in range(len(works) - hard_max):
        model.AddBoolOr([works[i] for i in range(start, start + hard_max + 1)])
```

I wonder if this would help speed up the solver.

Comment: I think you meant `works[i].Not()` instead of `works[i]` in the last line of your code.